How to control maximum and minimum coordinates in ImageMesh[]?
I  am  trying  to use ImageMesh to create a mesh from voxel data. On this mesh I would like to calculate the coordinates of the vertices sitting on the boundary, an equivalent approach would be to find the positions of these coordinates in the list of coordinates of the mesh). These I can then use for future calculations where I can apply boundary conditions for FEM etc.
As a test I create a simple 3D test image with 2 x 2 x 2 voxels half has the value 1 the other half 0. I then use the Marching Cubes algorithm to calculate a BoundaryMesh.
testimage = Image3D[Table[If[x > 1, 1, 0], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 1, 2}]]
mm = ImageMesh[testimage, Method -> "MarchingCubes"]


The mesh coordinates can be calculated using:
mc = MeshCoordinates[mm]

{{0.5, 2.00195, 0.5}, {-0.00195313, 1.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1.5, 1.00195}, {0.5, 1.5, -0.00195313}, {-0.00195313, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 1.00195}, {0.5, 0.5, -0.00195313}, {0.5, -0.00195313,  0.5}, {1.5, 2.00195, 0.5}, {1.5, 1.5, 1.00195}, {1.5, 1.5, -0.00195313}, {1.5, 0.5, 1.00195}, {1.5,   0.5, -0.00195313}, {1.5, -0.00195313, 0.5}, {2.00195, 1.5,   0.5}, {2.00195, 0.5, 0.5}}

Reading this list of coordinates shows that the coordinates sitting at the boundary at x=0 have approximately 0.002 (or0.00195313)units subtracted from it, and 0.002 units added for x=2. (The same goes for y and z). Interestingly this doesnt happen if we start off with a completely full mesh.
testimage = Image3D[Table[1, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 1, 2}]]
mm = ImageMesh[testimage, Method -> "MarchingCubes", DataRange -> {{0., 2.}, {0., 2.}, {0., 2.}}]
mc = MeshCoordinates[mm]

Here the mesh coordinates are :
{{0.5, 2., 1.5}, {0., 1.5, 1.5}, {0.5, 1.5, 2.}, {0.5, 2., 0.5}, {0.,   1.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1.5, 0.}, {0., 0.5, 1.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 2.}, {0., 0.5,   0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0., 1.5}, {0.5, 0., 0.5}, {1.5, 2.,   1.5}, {1.5, 1.5, 2.}, {1.5, 2., 0.5}, {1.5, 1.5, 0.}, {1.5, 0.5,   2.}, {1.5, 0.5, 0.}, {1.5, 0., 1.5}, {1.5, 0., 0.5}, {2., 1.5,  1.5}, {2., 1.5, 0.5}, {2., 0.5, 1.5}, {2., 0.5, 0.5}}

If I can fix the outer coordinates using DataRange -> {{0., 2.}, {0., 2.}, {0., 2.}}, for example then I can just use Position[mc,{0.,_,_}] to calculate the location of all coordinates that are sitting at x=0. DataRange doesn't seem to do this though and in the documentation I don't find much. Currently I need to use Something like Position[mc, {_?(-0.003 < # < -0.001 &), _, _}] where I hunt within a range of values for my x coordinates, ok but not so elegant.
My question.
Is there a way of controlling the Marching Cube Algorithm to give a boundary that actually sits at particular coordinates? That is if I have a 3D array of 1s and 0s with dimensions 10,10,10 how can I force the ImageMesh to put the minimum and maximum coordinates at 0.0 and 10.0 for x, y and z respectively?

Perhaps RegionResize?
